# Why I can't see my T-SQL string generated by a queryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, iqueryable

I'm noticed that some queries in my application are so slowly, so that's the reason why I want to know what is trying to accomplish my queries in LINQ TO SQL through entity framework.

In some sites, I realized that if you put your mouse over the IQueryable variable, you can see the T-SQL generated and at this moment, I can't see that.

[image]

I'd like to know if I'm doing a wrong configuration in my Entity Framework model

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Framework you can see generated SQL query by inspecting your context `Log` property, or you can cast your `IQueryable` to `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery` and use method `ToTraceString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest a different approach: Look at the real query in SQL Profiler. You can see all queries executed including parameter values. You can copy the query including parameter assignments to SSMS to debug it.